# Compressing using LZMA on-the-fly to a file?

Tags: ruby, csv, lzma

This code compress *on-the-fly* data using a `Bzip2` writer a `csv`file.

```ruby
File.open('file.bz2', 'wb') do |f|
  writer = Bzip2::Writer.new f
  CSV(writer) do |csv|
    (2**16).times { csv << arr }
  end
  writer.close
end
```

I want to do the same using `lzma` algorithm and [ruby-lzma](https://github.com/ianlevesque/ruby-lzma) gem could be useful, but this gem only one method `compressed = LZMA.compress('data to compress')`.

**Question**:

Is there a way to do a similar compression using `lzma`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ruby-xz](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-xz/) which has a much better interface to liblzma (using FFI).

The lib has `XZ::StreamWriter` class. Check the [docs](http://quintus.github.io/ruby-xz/) for ruby-xz

However `CSV` constructor does not take the `XZ::StreamWriter`, so you need to change the code to use `CSV.generate_line`. I was able to run this, which does generate the file on the fly

```
require 'xz'
require 'csv'

arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

File.open('file.xz', 'wb') do |f|
  XZ::StreamWriter.new(f) do |writer|
    (2**16).times { writer << CSV.generate_line(arr) }
    writer.finish
  end
end
```